# Jquery not loading in Brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

New to javascript and html. I have copied and pasted many suggestions on this topic to no avail. Really not sure what the problem is. Tried to get rid of everything that could be wrong and reordered the lines a few times. Here's the code in .html

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jitter.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

My jitter.js file puts errors up no what what I write, I started it with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
}
```

I've tried functions copied from online projects and simple ones but cannot get them to run.

With the above,
I get the error '$' was used before it was defined.
Which I think is because jquery isn't loading.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something silly but I cannot figure out what I am missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing document closing brackets  `$(document).ready(function(){ });`

Comment: Please download a copy of jquery, try again. if the problem still happen, then it's the problem of your jitter.js.

Comment: Problem is still persisting after downloading, so, there is something wrong with my jitter.js file?, Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

**With the above, I get the error '$' was used before it was defined.**
This means you are using jQuery before it was actually loaded.

src should be the path of the file something like this

```
<script src="./jitter.js"></script>
```

if it's on your root.

if this doesn't work you can download jQuery, save it and then provide the path in src of script tag.

Also there is a bracket missing in:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
// do something
})
```

Comment: "./jitter.js" did not fix it, although I thought it would. I downloaded jQuery, saved it as .js, linked it with  <script src="jQuery.js"></script>, same problem

Comment: Provide the path as <script src="./jQuery.js"></script>